# How to inline import another source in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In node.js Javascript I can do this:

```
class MyClass{
    data(){
        return [
            require('this-module'),
            require('another-module),
            require('that-module),
        ];
    }
}
```

In Typescript I can write:

```
import * as ThisModule from 'this-module'
import * as AnotherModule from 'another-module'
import * as ThatModule from 'that-module'

class MyClass{
    data():MyModuleTypeArray{
        return [
            ThisModule,
            AnotherModule,
            ThatModule
        ];
    }
}
```

But in that solution I must write each name 3 times.

**My question**: Can I wrote the code in Typescript for inline include or in some other way in which I don't need to write 3 times the name (or to use an auxiliar variable)?

Of course I can write `require` but `require` returns `any`. I want the type checking.

Comment: If you're using a recent version of TypeScript, you could use a [dynamic import expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#dynamic-import-expressions).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's asynchronous, this makes control flow unnecessary complicated.

Comment: `await import('this-module')` is complicated?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan `data` is. The thing you're suggesting is to convert intrinsically synchronous method to asynchronous for no good reason (and potentially all code that consumes `data`).

Comment: @estus I have no idea what `data()` does or how it's consumed. Do you? How do you know that making the method asynchronous is a bad thing? Anyway, it's a comment, not an answer, precisely because I don't have all of the information.

Comment: data() is a generic name. I have a big class that has a collection of other class (inheriting of the same base). I want to have each class definition in one separate file and the collection as simple as possible

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I surely don't too because the rest of the code wasn't shown, but from my experience this is a bad thing in most cases. I have a WTF moment almost every time when initially sync routine is replaced with async one (storage, auth, whatever), because async tends to be viral. Any way, dynamic import (with an explanation of possible complications provided) would be the correct answer here, at least a part of it; another part would be 'there's no other way'.

Comment: Technically you can use require in ts, maybe not what you want be it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The objective answer to your question is no, this is not possible. TypeScript /JavaScript currently does not provide a way to use `import` inline/synchronously in the same way `require` can be.

What you can do, though, is to call `import` dynamically as an async function. The direct implication of this change would be that your `data` method would have to be async.

The following would be the suggested implementation.

```js
class MyClass{
  async data() {
      return Promise.all([
          import('this-module'),
          import('another-module'),
          import('that-module'),
      ]);
  }
}
```